# Extract Word Information From MFCC

Tags: speech-recognition, mfcc

I am making a pronunciation Scoring system, and I need to know how to separate the pronunciation information of an MFCC of a given spoken word, so that later i can match this MFCC with  the MFCC of the word. can that be done threw matlab or HTK ?

Second Question:
In the matching part, shall I used DTW or standard edit distance algorithm or a simple MSE ??

Thanks in advance